# Flutter MacOS MethodChannel Communication to AppDelegate

Tags: swift, macos, flutter, flutter-desktop

How do you access the FlutterBinaryMessenger in the AppDelegate on the Swift side of a MacOS Flutter application?  In all the examples I have found, the AppDelegate is just a placeholder.  You need to get the FlutterBinaryMessenger to instantiate a FlutterMethodChannel to actually communicate to the Dart side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the current macOS template, the `FlutterViewController` (which lets you get the messenger, via `.engine.binaryMessenger`) is owned by the window, not the application. If you want to access it from the `AppDelegate` you'll need to wire up a connection between `AppDelegate` and `MainFlutterWindow`.

Comment: I had to modify the MainFlutterWindow.swift file to store the FlutterViewController in a static variable (horrible on both counts, I know) but it did work.